# How can I pass Bus signal input to simulink model during runtime

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model which takes Bus signal as input. I have passed the bus signal data using Configuration->Data import/export ->input
     Now I want to vary this signal from workspace when model is running and see the output during runtime.
     But model is taking new data from workspace only when you stop the model and run again. Is there any way to feed the input to model during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

By default Simulink looks in the Workspace for data at initialization, not at every time step.  Hence the behaviour you are seeing.

To make it look in the workspace during the simulation you need to force it to do so.  This can be done by using set_param to change a dialog parameter.

Once you've made a change to the variable in the workspace, in your case, something like `set_param(gcs,'ExternalInput',get_param(gcs,'ExternalInput'))` should work.

This is just getting the string that is in the dialog box and poking the (same) string back into the dialog.
This tells Simulink that something has changed and it'll go and re-read the variables.

Comment: I tried it but, it is not updating the workspace variable in the model.

Comment: Hi Phil,
    I think It is writing the same string in the dialog box again as you said, But to update the bus signal to model we need to click apply button programmatically or (something else is needed to feed the updated bus signal name to model).